# cx_Oracle unable to commit the changes

Tags: python, cx-oracle

`CALL MANAGE_NAME()` works in sqlplus and it update the data

where as 
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username,password,database);
    cursor= connection.cursor()

```
cursor.callproc("MANAGE_NAME");
connection.commit();
print  "Changes commited"
```

But the changes are not getting reflected

Comment: It's been a while since I've used cx_Oracle, but I believe adding the commit inside the procedure is the way to handle this. Have you tried that approach?

Comment: Committing in the app should be fine: unless the PL/SQL code is rolling back.  There isn't enough info in the problem description to comment more.

Answer (score 0):

```
sQuery = "commit"
curORA.execute(sQuery)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).